# Google-Cloud-Scheduler fail with http trigger Cloud Function

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

There is a Http trigger Cloud function that exec successfully.

Code of function:

[image]

Logging with stackdriver:

```
"Function execution took 301394 ms, finished with status code: 200"
```

Now, I create a cloud-scheduler to trigger this cloud-function each day at 04:00 am.

Scheduler-Logging with stackdriver:

```
{
 httpRequest: {…}  
  insertId: "..."  
  jsonPayload: {
   @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"   
   jobName: "......"   
   status: "UNKNOWN"   
   targetType: "HTTP"   
   url: "https://...."   
  }
  logName: "...."  
  receiveTimestamp: "2020-03-02T06:20:36.391816880Z"  
  resource: {…}  
  severity: "ERROR"  
  timestamp: "2020-03-02T06:20:36.391816880Z"  
 }
```

Comment: How is your function? does it need any parameters? Show us some code

Comment: @ajorquera My function doesn't need any parameters. Just use 'GET' Method

Comment: It seems like your CF takes a lot of time to execute. Of course you have expanded the deadline for the CF, but I believe that CS stops waiting for a response. Maybe you could try using  Pub/Sub to start the process without waiting for a response. [See the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to reproduce your issue and it's what I thought, the Cloud Scheduler is not waiting for the response from the Cloud Function. If you have a CF that takes at most 9 minutes to execute, even if you extend the deadline to 9 minutes, this is only on the CF side and the CS will stop waiting, leaving the request's status as UNKNOWN (therefore, FAILED).

If you are creating the CS from the sdk, you should take a look at the parameter [--attempt-deadline](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/scheduler/jobs/create/http#--attempt-deadline), which will allow the CS to wait more.

If you don't need to see the response from the CS, you could try using [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub) to start the process without waiting.

Answer (score 1):

What we found and confirmed by Google Support:
1. Job created through GCP Cloud Console only works for 60secs  and it returns FAILED even if the Cloud Function is set for maximum of 540secs. Note, CF will execute successfully.
2. To overcome, create the job through command line using gcloud SDK command:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/http

It returned SUCCESS when we set the --attempt-deadline=1200s, which is above 540secs CF execution time.

Hope this helps